# automorphisms and normal bundle

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective algebraic variety and $Z$ a smooth closed subvariety of $X$. Let $f: X \to X$ be an automorphism of $X$ such that $f(Z)\subset Z$.

How does $f$ act on the normal bundle $N_{Z/X}$?

Answer (score 2):

$N_{Z/X} = TX|_Z/TZ$. By your assumption, $Tf:TX\to TX$ maps the restriction $TX|_Z$ to itself, and also $TZ\to TZ$, with the same foot-point mapping $Z\to Z$. Thus it induces 
$TX|_Z/TZ\to TX|_Z/TZ$.